# Find all the accumulation points and all the isolated points of the set $e^{i[ {n\pi}/2 + 1/n ]}$ where $n$ is an integer.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have started the working on this problem and I'm not sure how to finish it. I know that graphically the set represents four sections of on the unit circle. My thought was that each section will get closer and close to $1$, $i$, $-1$, and $-i$. These points would be the accumulation points and the rest of the set would be the isolated points, similarly to how $i/n$ has only zero as an accumulation point.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to section the positive integers according to their remainders when divided by 4.

$$e^{\pi in/2+i/n}=e^{i/4k}\quad\text{for } n=4k, k\in\Bbb N^+$$
$$e^{\pi in/2+i/n}=ie^{i/(4k+1)}\quad\text{for }n=4k+1,k\in\Bbb N^+$$
$$e^{\pi in/2+i/n}=-e^{i/(4k+2)}\quad\text{for }n=4k+2,k\in\Bbb N^+$$
$$e^{\pi in/2+i/n}=-ie^{i/(4k+3)}\quad\text{for }n=4k+3, k\in\Bbb N^+.$$